# updating macos version from Big Sur to Montrey lead to OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 30100010, you have 30200000

Tags: git, macos, ssh, openssl, homebrew

my osx version was originaly Big Sur and SSH and SSL were working fine until I updated to Montrey.

since the update, I can't use SSH or pull from Github and I get this error.

```
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 30100010, you have 30200000
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

what i have done so far:

I reinstalled ruby and openssl from homebrew and reinstalled it again as per one of the solutions i found on github using

```
brew reinstall ruby
brew reinstall openssl
```

now when i do `openssl version -a` this is the result:

```
OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023)
built on: Thu Nov 23 13:20:19 2023 UTC
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: clang -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl@3"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/lib/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/lib/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_ia32cap=0x7ffaf3ffffebffff:0x29c6fbf
```

output for `where openssl`:

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
/Users/m-store/opt/anaconda3/bin/openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

output for `which openssl`:

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

output for `brew link --force openssl`:

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1
To relink, run:
  brew unlink openssl@3 && brew link openssl@3
```

output for `nano ~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0_1/bin/openssl"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/m-store/Library/Android/sdk
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/m-store/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/m-store/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
alias pip='noglob pip'
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/m-store/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/m-store/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/m-store/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/m-store/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/m-store/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/m-store/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi
# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/m-store/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/m-store/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
```

despite these, the error still persists, i have looked at every post related to this and tried to implement them but could not, most of them were for ubuntu and apt package manager.

I would appreciate it if any one could provide some clarity, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a Homebrew git, or git from some other source?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `brew install openssh` it worked for me.

Comment: I don't understand why - but it worked for me as well.